# plupload doesn't redirect to url

Tags: plupload

I'm using plupload to upload image files to server.
javascript code is taken directly from the sample page from plupload web site:

```
    <div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>
                <button id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;" />Dosya Seç<br /><br />

                 <button  id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;" />YÜKLE<br /><br /> 
                    <pre id="console"></pre>
              <script type="text/javascript">
// Custom example logic

var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
    container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
    url : 'yonetim.asp?id=13&sid=1&emlak=<%=emlakid%>',
     resize : {width : 400, height : 300, quality : 99},
    filters : {
        max_file_size : '15mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
        ]
    },

    init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                uploader.start();
                return false;
            };
        },

        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<br><br><div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
            });
        },

        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        },

        UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
            // Called when all files are either uploaded or failed
            console.log('[UploadComplete]');
            window.location = 'yonetim.asp?id=13&sid=1&emlak=<%=emlakid%>';
        },
        Error: function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
        }
    }
});

uploader.init();

</script>
```

script seems to be work; it loads the image file when I click start-upload button and indicates the percentage. But at the end it doesn't redirect to upload page namely "yonetim.asp", indeed it stays at the same page and gives 200 http error.
Any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that the upload complete event is UploadComplete. You're not binding that event.

```
UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
  // Called when all files are either uploaded or failed
  console.log('[UploadComplete]');
  window.location = 'yonetim.asp';
 },
```

source: example documentation http://www.plupload.com/examples/events

Comment: isn't it for to log the result only? Does it affect to go or not to upload page (yonetim.asp)?
I added UploadComplete event to the script and result is the same.

Comment: Please update your question to show how you implemented this. It works for me on several sites.

Comment: I update the answer to also forward a browser to the page you asked. please select my answer.

Comment: I update my code.
It redirects to yonetim.asp but with the empty data. 
The line (in yonetim.asp)
    dosyaadi=File.Filename
gives an empty filename.

Comment: This is a bare bones example. please select my answer as correct and ask your separate question as a separate question.

Comment: That is a logical game but not the correct answer. You manually redirect after script stops. Plupload redirects to the "url" when it finishes its job, isn't it? Problem here is when it finishes his work doesn't post any data to "url" neither goes "url". 
Since your answer "logically" correct for the way that question asked, I select your answer correct but please note that your answer didin't solve the problem.
Anyway, thank you for your help.